# How are the MSN XMPP JID hashes calculated?

Tags: hash, xmpp, msn-messenger

MSN messenger (windoze live connect or whatever they call it nowadays) over XMPP doesn't use the actual email addresses for buddy JIDs, but somekindofhashes@messenger.live.com
These hashes can be looked up using getjid, but I am wondering if anybody knows how they are actually calculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no way to calculate them for security reason. The GetJid stuff is the only way to lookup them.